# Select row depending on if another table row exists

Tags: sql, postgresql

It's hard to write a good title for this one...

I have 4 tables in my postgresql database:

```
courses:
| id | data | created_at | updated_at | status |

course_versions:
| id | course_id | data | created_at | updated_at | status |

course_progresses:
| id | course_version_id | user_id | data | created_at | updated_at |

users:
| id | email |
```

A course can have multiple course_versions and a user can have course_progresses and each course_progress is connected to a course_version. Now, I want to fetch all course_versions for a specific user, that is if a user has no course_progress for a course_version of `course id: 1` it should return the latest course_version. If the user has a course_progress for a course_version of `course id: 2` that course_version should be returned, regardless if there are newer course_versions… Get it? :)

This is a query that works:

```
WITH
course_versions_with_progress AS (
  SELECT cv.*
  FROM course_versions AS cv
  INNER JOIN courses AS c ON c.id = cv.course_id
  INNER JOIN course_progresses AS cp ON cp.course_version_id = cv.id
  WHERE c.status = 1 AND cv.status = 1 AND cp.user_id = 123
),
latest_course_versions AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT ON(cv.course_id) cv.*
  FROM course_versions AS cv
  INNER JOIN courses AS c ON c.id = cv.course_id
  WHERE c.status = 1 AND cv.status = 1
  ORDER BY cv.course_id, cv.created_at DESC
)
SELECT * FROM course_versions_with_progress
UNION
  SELECT * FROM latest_course_versions
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM course_versions_with_progress
    WHERE course_id = latest_course_versions.course_id
  )
```

It looks quite horrible to me though… Is there a better way to write this query?

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to write something without example data from you but:

```
with -- Example data, just to check that there are no syntax errors 
    courses(id, status) as (values
        (1,1),(2,1),(3,0)),
    course_versions(id, course_id, status, created_at) as (values
        (1,1,1,current_timestamp),(2,1,1,current_timestamp),(3,2,1,current_timestamp),(4,2,0,current_timestamp)),
    course_progresses(id, course_version_id, user_id) as (values
        (2,3,123))
select distinct on (cp.course_version_id, cv.course_id)
    cv.*
from
    course_versions as cv
        join courses as c on (c.id = cv.course_id and c.status = 1 and cv.status = 1)
        left join course_progresses cp on (cp.course_version_id = cv.id and cp.user_id = 123)
order by
    cp.course_version_id nulls last, cv.course_id, cv.created_at desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `cross join` to create a 2D matrix of users and courses.  For each entry, look up either the version with progress, or the latest version:

```
select  u.email
,       c.course_id
,       coalesce(progress_version.created_at, latest_version.created_at)
from    users u
cross join
        courses c
left join
        (
        select  cp.user_id
        ,       cv.course_id
        ,       cv.created_at
        from    course_progresses cp
        join    course_versions cv
        on      cv.id = cp.course_version_id
        ) progress_version
on      progress_version.user_id = u.id
        and progress_version.course_id = c.id
left join
        (
        select  row_number() over (partition by course_id 
                                   order by created_at desc) rn
        ,       *
        from    course_versions
        ) latest_version
on      latest_version.course_id = c.id
        and latest_version.rn = 1
```